# How to pass HTML/PHP button to execute MYSQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql, button

Hi guys sorry if my previous questions isn't clear enough, but it came to my senses that my real problem is I can't pass the button click event to execute MYSQL query.

Here is my button that supposed to be when clicked is to execute the query

```
<form action="invoice.php" method="post">
<input type='submit' name='hehe' />
</form>
```

Then consider I have established a database connection, here is the code i want to do the trick but it does nothing when the hehe button is clicked

```
if(isset($_POST['hehe'])){
    $result=mysql_query("   
            SELECT a.id, a.name, s.descc, a.phone, a.start, a.end, a.price
            from wp_app_appointments a 
            LEFT JOIN wp_app_services s 
            ON a.id=s.id
            WHERE a.status ='confirmed'
            order by a.name 
            ");
}
```

Then I want it to display here.

```
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))

                {   
                if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
                    {
                    $id = $test['id'];  
                    echo "<tr align='center'>"; 
                    /*echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['id']."</font></td>";*/
                    echo"<td style='width:200px'></td>";
                    echo"<td style='width:500px'>" .$test['name']."</td>";
                    echo"<td style='width:200px'>". $test['descc']. "</td>";
                    echo"<td style='width:200px'>". $test['phone']. "</td>";
                    echo"<td style='width:200px'>". $test['start']. "</td>"; 
                    echo"<td style='width:200px'>". $test['end']. "</td>";  
                    echo"<td style='width:200px'>". $test['price']. "</td>";    
                    echo"<td style='width:200px'> <a href ='print.php.?id=$id' target=_blank >Print</a>";
                    echo"<td style='width:100px'></td>";        
                    echo "</tr>";

                }
                            }
```

Sorry for the previous questions.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions & why use double & single quotes in same HTML ?

Comment: Have you tried running the mysql code manually and seeing if it actually runs properly?

Comment: Sorry im just a beginner. What should I use? The mysql_* function you say is the one im using on my search query. and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham: Yes it do run properly.

Comment: Use either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql_query. Are you sure the code is being run at all (i.e., echo out a statement if hehe is set)

Comment: Yes it do runs. And about it is being echoed. i don't know? I just copy the logic of my search box that runs properly.
`if (isset($_POST['search']))
   {
   $name =$_POST['name'];
   $result=mysql_query("
   SELECT a.id, a.name, s.descc, a.phone, a.start, a.end, a.price
   from wp_app_appointments a 
   LEFT JOIN wp_app_services s 
   ON a.id=s.id
   WHERE a.status ='confirmed' and a.name LIKE '$name%'
   or a.email LIKE '$name%'
   or a.phone LIKE '$name%'  
   or a.address LIKE '$name%'  
   ");
   }`

And i can't view the link you provided. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="invoice.php" method="post">
<input type='submit' name='hehe' />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['hehe']))
{
    $result=mysqli_query($con, "   
        SELECT a.id, a.name, s.descc, a.phone, a.start, a.end, a.price
        from wp_app_appointments a 
        LEFT JOIN wp_app_services s 
        ON a.id=s.id
        WHERE a.status ='confirmed'
        order by a.name 
        ");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0)
    {       
        while($test = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {               
            $id = $test['id'];  
            echo "<tr align='center'>"; 
            echo "<td style='width:200px'></td>";
            echo "<td style='width:500px'>".$test['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td style='width:200px'>". $test['descc']. "</td>";
            echo "<td style='width:200px'>". $test['phone']. "</td>";
            echo "<td style='width:200px'>". $test['start']. "</td>"; 
            echo "<td style='width:200px'>". $test['end']. "</td>";  
            echo "<td style='width:200px'>". $test['price']. "</td>";    
            echo "<td style='width:200px'> <a href ='print.php.?id=$id' target=_blank >Print</a>";
            echo "<td style='width:100px'></td>";        
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

*it should be saved as 'invoice.php'

*db connection should be 'mysqli'

eg:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks. It works like a charm, im having trouble displaying all the columns but i think i can manage it due to my first code. Thanks!